Mastubation and ghusl
If a girl mastubate but nothing is released from a body, after sometime a transparent fluid is little bit released is ghusl mandatory ??

Shia fiqh's answer is simply "No", since it is obligated only if the fluid was coming out at the time of Orgasm (refs here and here in Persian)
Meanwhile, in case you know not, masturbation is considered self-marriage and is forbidden, and the ejaculated liquid (if it ejaculated at all) is Najis (unclean).

Assalamu Alaykum,
Firstly, masturbation is Haram according to many scholars, so please try to stop doing that. In regards to your question, if the fluid was released as part of orgasm, then it is required that you do Ghusl. If it was released after your orgasm and desire faded away, then it doesn't require Ghusl. Please note I am not a scholar sister so it's still better to ask somewhere where a Muft/Sheikh can answer like IslamQA or something like that. I hope this helped to answer your question.
